# Firebase Storage - Images not returning when using VPN

Tags: firebase, vpn

I am currently building a web app using Angular and using Firebase Storage for storing images.

I've noticed that when I'm using Nord VPN, I cannot look at my images. For example:

Nord VPN active, set in UK:
[image: Image called with VPN active]

No Nord VPN:
[image: Image call with no VPN active]

This is also the same when running code from a machine with Nord active.

I guess my questions are:

1. Do Google actively block VPN users?
2. Is there a way around this?

I pay for a VPN so that I don't have Google tracking my every move, I don't want to have to turn my VPN off just so I can develop apps.

I've tested this on:
Chrome,
Brave

**EDIT**: I've found out that it's actually CyberSec that is blocking anything that comes from my CDN. Following the [Nord VPN support page](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/1087249732/I-can-t-reach-some-websites-with-VPN-connected.htm).

Following steps 3 & 4 seemed to work for me and I've now submitted a support email to Nord!

Answer (score 1):

Google ban you because vpn public ips are limited and your ip has been used by another user at same time, In simple word at this situation google security devices think at the same time multiple requests from one human device is not possible (and probably you are a machine :)) and then ban you.

Comment: I thought this may be the case. It just sucks that I have to work without my VPN on. As I said, I have a VPN to get away from the tracking 

Comment: Because i use VPN services alot, every day google think "i am a machine" ( with Arnold Schwarzenegger accent ) :-)

Comment: Turns out it was because I had CyberSec enabled with NordVPN. I've submitted a support email to them.

Comment: as i know CyberSec option in NordVPN designed to block ads for users, tanks for the info.

Comment: Yeah it blocks malicious sites, botnets and phishing scams. Maybe it saw the Firebase CDN as a malicious link 